# How can I efficiently sample random posts in Django, when each post uses UUIDs rather than sequential IDs?

Tags: python, django, random, django-queryset

I have some post models where the ID is a UUID.
Now I want to display some random post proposals the user may also like to see at my post_detail template...

This is how I process the post proposals the user may also like to see at views.py:

```
def post_proposals():
    post_elements = sorted(
        chain(
            Model1.objects.all(),
            Model2.objects.all(),
            Model3.objects.all()
        )
    )
    post_elements_list = list(post_elements) # Conversion to list is requierd by random
    post_proposals = random.sample(post_elements_list)
    return post_proposals


def post_detail(request, pk):
    ...
  args = {
    'post': post,
    'post_proposals': post_proposals(),
  ...
```

template.html:

```
 {% for post_proposal in post_proposals %}
    <h1>{{ post_proposal.title }}</h1>
 {% endfor %}
```

The problem now is that this would kill my database performance from my understanding... As soon as I have a lot of posts stored at my database the query will become massive. I first have to get all elements of 3 models and then get 10 random entries from the list each time a post gets displayed to the user.

I also found the following which seems to be quite useful:

https://elpenia.wordpress.com/2010/05/11/getting-random-objects-from-a-queryset-in-django/

Sadly I can't use that solution as I work with UUIDs which are non-sequential strings instead of int values I would have with IDs.

Comment: Are those 3 models related somewhere?

Comment: @SwetankPoddar: What exactly do you mean by "related somewhere"? They are indeed quite similar but dont have a direct interaction and are independent from each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have different models, which makes the operation very expensive.
I would suggest you to add a new model where all of the models you want to query are registered as foreign keys or id/type pair. With that you can bypass the design flaw and either

1. pull the ids only: 
   model.objects.all().values_list('id',flat=True). 
   the result of the  random.sample will be ids and you can pull the posts using the id directly
2. generate a random range between 1 and count() of the new table and then pull the actual posts by processing the records with the corresponding index. This will require you to add an index field, since id's may not be sequential(deleting and stuff)

once you get the ids you can pull the set with model.objects.filter(id__in=post_proposals) and process it further

--- EDIT a sample implementation ---

a model that wraps around the other models will look something like this:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
   @staticmethod
   def get_ref_type(): return 0

   def create(self):
      super(Model1,self).create()
      Posts.register(self,Model1.get_ref_type())

   def delete(self):
      Posts.un_register(self,Model1.get_ref_type())
      super(Model1,self).delete()

class Posts(models.Model):
  class Meta: 
    ....

  #sequential index, this is what you will filter against
  index    = models.IntegerField(default=0)
  #type of the model you want to query
  ref_type = models.IntegerField(default =-1)
  #id of the record in the table defined in the ref_type field
  ref_id   = models.IntegerField(default =-1)

  @staticmethod
  def register(f_objRecord,f_intType):
      l_objWrp = Posts()
      #a separate table that will be used to hold the free indexes
      #it will ensure that even when you delete records, there
      #won't be any holes in the set
      l_objWrp.index = PostIndex.get_index()
      l_objWrp.ref_id = f_objRecord.id 
      l_objWrp.ref_type = f_intType

      l_objWrp.save()

  @staticmethod
  def un_register(f_objRecord,f_intType):
     l_objWrp = Posts.objects.get(ref_type=f_intType,ref_id=f_objRecord.id)
     PostIndex.free_index(l_objWrp.index)
     l_objWrp.delete()
  def get_data(self):
     l_intRefType = self.ref_type
     l_intId      = self.ref_id

     l_objRecord = None
     if l_intRefType == Model1.get_ref_type():
        l_objRecord = Model1.objects.get(id=l_intId)
     elif l_intRefType == Model2.get_ref_type():
       .....

     if l_objRecord: 
        #pull the data you want
     else: raise('unknown model type')
```

Comment: Thanks for your example, this might work, I will try to get things done in the next couple of days and report back, merci :D

Comment: Can you provide me some more information on how the model has to look like?! Would be awesome.

Comment: I updated the comment, You will have to figure the index tracking on your own though. It is not that difficult, and I can't throw more time into this, Hope it gets you started.

Answer (score 0):

You could try getting the database to order randomly and then slice, for example

```
Model1.objects.order_by('?')[:3]`.
```

The [`order_by`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) docs warn that this may be expensive and slow, but it might be worth testing to see whether it gives acceptable results in practice.

Comment: I also came across this solution and the result was sad and simple "No". It might be a working solution but in the end with 3 models, this would also kill the DB performance as soon as a couple of users are online.